# API to get IBM WebSphere MQ version?

Tags: c++, c, ibm-mq

Is there any way to get IBM WebSphere MQ version and patch level, both client and manager side? I am looking for the same data that is shown by dspmqver but through the C/C++ API.

Answer (score 1):

You call `MQINQ`, passing the Queue Manager handle, with the selectors for `MQIA_COMMAND_LEVEL` and `Version` is an attribute of the `MQCFST` structure.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q101840_.htm

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to Stavr00 answer that compile-time define of WMQ library is MQCMDL_CURRENT_LEVEL

P.S. Yet other details reported by dspmqver (like CMVC level, build type etc.) remain hidden within WMQ API internals :(